# Are there any laid down guidelines to enrich and strengthen Christian faith?

Tags: catholicism, faith, christian-living

I was asked to devise a brief note on how to strengthen and enrich faith in Christianity.

Are there any laid down guidelines in Roman Catholicism as to how this is achieved? If any such documents exists in Protestantism would be also helpful if their basic beliefs are conforming to Nicene Creed.

Comment: @jayyeshu this is still really broad, I'd encourage you to focus on specific aspects of the topic rather than the breadth of it. Even within a denomination there might be many volumes written on the topic

Comment: You mean like st. Ignatius of loyolas spiritual exercises?

Comment: The answer from @rowen is indicative that this question could be answered irrespective of any denomination and thst is what I was looking for. Yet any reference from an official document would have helped.

Answer (score 3):

Broadly here are a few points which can greatly help to strengthen us in our faith:

1. Know the steps and daily chores of how to persevere in maintaining and enriching one's own faith. See the link provided in comments from @Wikis.
2. Teaching skills and imparting an in-depth religious knowledge to defend the faith.
3. Making known to everyone which are the susceptible areas where Satan would initiates his lure, for making us weak in our faith.
4. Making aware of the uniqueness, strong points and truthfulness of Christianity.
5. Teaching the hollowness, deceptiveness and errors in other faith. This aspect has been woefully and foolishly kept out of syllabus of our Catechism classes and we are paying a heavy price for it. On the other hand other faiths are solely dependent on this aspect for their propagation since they hardly stand an in-depth scrutiny of their own faith and prosper by deceptively propagating negative information about our faith.
6. Imparting training on how to strike a conversation with people of other faith so as to make them aware we are on much stronger ground and where they falter readily.
7. Teaching and exhorting Christians to live their faith in their daily dealings with outside world, especially with non believers and in public. They need to be taught for not to feel awkward in practicing Christian faith in public places.
8. Teaching Christians to be good example to people of other faith so that as Jesus said ' world would know that we are disciples of Jesus' and not to give an impression that we are not practicing what has been taught by Jesus as was once commented by Mahatma Gandhi.

I am not aware of any official document on similar lines from any of denomination. It highly probable that something on these lines would definitely be available somewhere.

Comment: I like this answer, because it works at the conceptual level, directing to the way we think. Why are we looking at denominations, traditions and creeds for guidance? God gave us the Scriptures. And God send us His own Holy Spirit to guide us. We need to stop mystifying Him and start realizing that Christianity is a supernaturally-powered enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few passages in the bible such as [Hebrews 10:23-25](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/hebrews/10/#v58010023):

> *"Let us hold firmly the **public declaration of our hope** without wavering, for the one who promised is faithful. 24  And let us consider one another so as to **incite to love and fine works**, 25 not forsaking our **meeting together**, as some have the custom, but encouraging one another, and all the more so as you see the day drawing near."*

So at our Christian meetings we can up-build and encourage one another. This can be anything from a quick complement, conversation, making plans for bible study, so on.

Another way of strengthening our faith is spreading our knowledge of the bibles message of hope publicly.